# How to split a dict as per certain parts of the keys or extract values only for the keys have similar keywords

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I am pretty new in Python. I have a dict with values for some of the dates of different months. I want to split the dictionary as dates of each month or I want to get sum of the values for any or each days's of a month. I can get sum of the values for the whole dictionary but couldn't figure out how to get results as stated above.
Here is my exiting dict:

```
Dict_Date_Vol = {'1/02/2021': 106239800, '2/02/2021': 83305400, '1/03/2021': 89880900, '3/03/2021': 84183100}
```

I want create a two new dict from here as like these two dictionaries:
`Dict_Feb = {'1/02/2021': 106239800, '2/02/2021': 83305400}` and
`Dict_Mar = {'1/03/2021': 89880900, '3/03/2021': 84183100}`
or simply I want to get Values for Feb: and Values for Mar as two separate variables.
Right now I can sum of all the values with the code below:

```
d = Dict_Date_Vol
def returnSum(d):
    sum =0
    for i in d:
        sum = sum + d[i]
    return sum
print('Total sum: ', returnSum(d))
```

I also can get a new dic for just a single key as below:

```
feb_vol = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in ('1/02/2021')}
print(feb_vol)
output: {'1/02/2021': 106239800}
```

However, I wanted to sort all of the keys based on the parts of keys (i.e. '02') so I can make a new dict for the month of Feb or with '03' for Mar. Any help would be highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was able to get what you are trying to do by looping over the dictionary and using the split method on the dates (which are strings) to split out the second element and see if it matches what we are looking for.

```
def getMonth(d,month):
    newDict = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k.split('/')[1] == month:
            newDict[k] = (v)
    return newDict
```

You pass in your same data dictionary, as well as a string for the month (so '02' for February). It then initializes a newDict, and then loops over the items. `k.split` breaks the dates (the keys) into chunks based on the '/', and we want the second element (starting at 0, so 1 is the second) to equal our month we passed in. If it does, we add then key-value pair. Afterward, we return that newDict.

Overall, here is the whole code, yours plus what I added:

```
Dict_Date_Vol = {
    '1/02/2021': 106239800,
    '2/02/2021': 83305400,
    '1/03/2021': 89880900,
    '3/03/2021': 84183100
}

d = Dict_Date_Vol
def returnSum(d):
    sum =0
    for i in d:
        sum = sum + d[i]
    return sum
print('Total sum: ', returnSum(d))

def getMonth(d,month):
    newDict = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k.split('/')[1] == month:
            newDict[k] = (v)
    return newDict

print(getMonth(d,'02'))
print('Total sum for Feb', returnSum(getMonth(d,'02')))
```

And it returned this:

```
Total sum:  363609200
{'1/02/2021': 106239800, '2/02/2021': 83305400}
Total sum for Feb 189545200
```

Comment: Exactly, this is the thing i wanted to do. You have saved me a lot. I have added one more line to get the average for each month with this line: `returndSum(getMonth(d,'02')/len(returndSum(getMonth(d,'02'))`.  It works perfectly. thanks again for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary where you group the dates by month (I'm assuming you have only unique dates):

```
Dict_Date_Vol = {
    "1/02/2021": 106239800,
    "2/02/2021": 83305400,
    "1/03/2021": 89880900,
    "3/03/2021": 84183100,
}

months = {}
for k, v in Dict_Date_Vol.items():
    months.setdefault(k.split("/")[1], {})[k] = v

print(months)
```

Prints:

```py
{'02': {'1/02/2021': 106239800, '2/02/2021': 83305400}, '03': {'1/03/2021': 89880900, '3/03/2021': 84183100}}
```

Then you can assign to your variables:

```
dict_feb = months.get("02")
dict_march = months.get("03")

print(dict_feb)
print(dict_march)
```

Prints:

```py
{'1/02/2021': 106239800, '2/02/2021': 83305400}
{'1/03/2021': 89880900, '3/03/2021': 84183100}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the years are all the same:

```py
from itertools import groupby

Dict_Date_Vol = {'1/02/2021': 106239800, '2/02/2021': 83305400, '1/03/2021': 89880900, '3/03/2021': 84183100}

def keyfunc(item):
    return item[0].split('/')[0]

for k, g in groupby(sorted(((k, v) for k, v in Dict_Date_Vol.items()), key=keyfunc), key=keyfunc):
    total = sum(t[1] for t in g)
    print('month =', k, 'total =', total)
```

Prints:

```
month = 1 total = 196120700
month = 2 total = 83305400
month = 3 total = 84183100
```

Comment: The keyfunc()  do the job perfectly, only index of the item had to changed to '1' to split the date for months. I have consider other answer as that is seems easier to maintain.

Comment: My mistake: In my country (locale), month is the first number. So the `keyfunc` should just be changed to return `item[0].split('/')[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can validate your data while building a single dictionary.

```
>>> Dict_Date_Vol = {'1/02/2021': 10, '2/02/2021': 10, '1/04/2021': 100, '2/04/2021': 100, '01/03/2020': 200, '1/4/2
020': 100}

>>> dates = {}
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> for k, v in Dict_Date_Vol.items():
...     date = datetime.strptime(k, '%d/%m/%Y')
...     year = str(date.year)
...     month = str(date.month)
...     if year not in dates:
...         dates[year] = {}
...     if month not in dates[year]:
...         dates[year][month] = {}
...
...     dates[year][month][k] = v
...
...
>>> dates
{'2021': {'2': {'1/02/2021': 10, '2/02/2021': 10}, '4': {'1/04/2021': 100, '2/04/2021': 100}}, '2020': {'3': {'01/03
/2020': 200}, '4': {'1/4/2020': 100}}}
```

Then, for instance, getting Feb/2021 dates:

```
>>> dates['2021']['2']
{'1/02/2021': 10, '2/02/2021': 10}
```